# Combining paste and cat in unix

Tags: unix, paste, cut

I have files with this name format:

```
<name1>.<name2>.<id>.ERR
```

where `name1` and `name2` are `character` `string`s and `id` is a number and all three are unique to each file. (these are standard output files from a `slurm` run,  and `id` is the job id).

I want to find out if these jobs failed so I was thinking of `cut`'ing `id` from each file name:

```
ls -1 *.ERR | cut -d "." -f 3
```

And then pasting `"sacct -j "` in front of it.
Is there a one liner that achieves this so that it runs:

`sacct -j id`*1*

`sacct -j id`*2*

```
.
.
```

`sacct -j id`*n*

Comment: I think that the tags CUT and PASTE are unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
for id in $(ls *.ERR | cut -d "." -f 3); do echo "machine: $id"; done
```

will work, if the files are not a lot (thousands). Replace echo blah blah with sacct -j, like this:

```
for id in $(ls *.ERR | cut -d "." -f 3); do sacct -j $id; done
```

There are other ways too.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `xargs`:

```
ls -1 *.ERR | cut -d "." -f 3 | xargs -L 1 sacct -j
```

which you can run in parallel with the `-P` option to alleviate a bit the latency from interrogating the database.

```
ls -1 *.ERR | cut -d "." -f 3 | barges -P 4 -L 1 sacct -j
```